# Auth0 and Nuxt JS 400 ( Unable to fetch script source ) error when logging in

Tags: vue.js, authentication, nuxt.js, auth0

Im pretty new to the nuxt realm and was running into a 400 page anytime trying to login. I follow the directions straight from the [Auth/nuxt Docs](https://auth.nuxtjs.org/providers/auth0) other than adding an ENV file.

Ive also added my Application URIs to allow my local host

Here is my `Nuxt.config.js` file with all the auth0 config inside.

```
export default {
  // Modules: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules
  modules: [
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
    '@nuxtjs/pwa',
    '@nuxtjs/auth-next',
  ],

  axios: {
    baseURL: 'http://localhost:5000',
  },

  env: {
    DOMAIN: process.env.DOMAIN,
    CLIENT_ID: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
    REDIRECT_URI: process.env.REDIRECT_URI,
  },

  // Auth0 Authentication

  auth: {
    redirect: {
      login: '/login', // redirect user when not connected
      logout: '/',
      callback: '/home',
    },
    strategies: {
      auth0: {
        domain: process.env.DOMAIN,
        client_id: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
        audience: 'https://MyApiLinkFromAuth0',
      },
    },
  },
}
```

And here is my component in the `/login` page.

```
<template>
  <div>
    Login Page
    <div>
      <button @click="login">Login</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    login() {
      this.$auth.loginWith('auth0')
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you missed something in your code sample, then the lack of an `audience` configuration is your problem:

[From the docs](https://auth.nuxtjs.org/providers/auth0/#obtaining-clientid-domain-and-audience)

> clientId and domain are REQUIRED. Your application needs some details about this client to communicate with Auth0.
>
> **audience is required unless you've explicitly set a default audience on your Auth0 tenant.**

Keep in mind you can configure the default audience by going to your dashboard, clicking the tenant dropdown (top left) and selecting Settings. Then scroll down to API authorization settings and enter a default audience.

Comment: Hey Adam thanks for getting back. Ive added my audience, as well as accepting my local host in the auth0 URIs settings. Im still being redirected to the 400 page

Comment: @Pwntastic what are the details of the 400 error? It should tell you what's wrong with your request.

Comment: In the error it shows `Unable to fetch script source.` but my request url looks fine. query params are fine.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out its a typo in the `client_id`. It should be `clientId`. The auth0 logs helped.